# How to change "medium" of Google Analytics with Tag Manager?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

On ads or campaigns I don't use the "utm", I use other methods (dimensions). However, I need to change the "medium" of "Source/medium" on my view of Google Analytics because Google detects, for example, "outlook.live.com / referral" and I would like to change "referral" to "email".

I have changed "channels grouping" for things with similar data but...

Does there exist an alternative method, for example through Tag Manager?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

On view level you can create channel grouping.

[image]

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

In GTM you can change this either in a GA settings variable or directly in your tag by using the "fields to set" option. The field name input has an autosuggest feature, so if you start typing "campaign" it will suggest "campaignMedium", "campaignSource" and other campaign related fields. In the right hand field you enter the custom value you want, either as fixed value or as GTM variable.

[image]